# There was no endpoint listening although started my service

Tags: c#, wcf, tcp

Please see this code:

```
namespace Server.Contracts
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IMessageService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        void DoWork(string message);
    }
}
```

**Server**

```
namespace Server
{
    [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
    public class MessageService : IMessageService
    {
        public void DoWork(string message)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(message);
        }
    }
}
```

**Client**

```
namespace Client
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int i = 0;
            var location = new[] { "London", "Paris", "New York", "Tokyo" };
            if (Process.GetProcessesByName(Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName).Length <= 2)
            {
                // Start my Server...
                Process.Start(@"C:\Server\bin\Debug\Server.exe");
            }

            i = Process.GetProcessesByName(Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName).Length;
            string loc = location[i];
            new Program().Stt(loc);

        }

        private void Stt(string loc)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Press ank key to continue...");
            Console.ReadLine();

            var uri = "net.tcp://localhost:4565/MessageService";
            var binding = new NetTcpBinding(SecurityMode.None);
            var channel = new ChannelFactory<IMessageService>(binding);
            var endpoint = new EndpointAddress(uri);
            var proxy = channel.CreateChannel(endpoint);
            if (proxy != null)
                proxy.DoWork(loc);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }       
    }
}
```

So after i start my `server` and both the `server` and the `clients` running i want to send message:

```
if (proxy != null)
    proxy.DoWork(loc);
```

So at this point i got this error although my server up and running:

> System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException: 'There was no endpoint
>   listening at net.tcp://localhost:4565/MessageService that could accept
>   the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP
>   action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.'

Comment: how do you host the service on the server side? which will determine the service address. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/how-to-host-a-wcf-service-in-a-managed-application

Comment: I would like you could post more details about your servicehost so that gives you an useful reply.